# available fonts in android ( from context.getAssets() ) java

Tags: java, android, graphics, fonts, typeface

First off, I'm a total noob. I have tried to look online for a list of the available fonts in Android. I want to have the names so that I can choose a font when drawing text. This is the method I will be using to set my font:

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
...
...
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "/*someSpecificFont.ttf*/");
...
```

Once I find out the names of the fonts, how would I specify the String so that a "FontNotFound" (if such an error exists, probably more like FileNotFound) is not thrown?

Thanks 
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 3 fonts available as part of android; normal (Droid Sans), serif (Droid Serif), and monospace (Droid Sans Mono). Here is a post that can help you to find how to enumerate fonts in android:

http://www.ulduzsoft.com/2012/01/enumerating-the-fonts-on-android-platform/